# Filtering a Scala Either list for failures

Tags: scala, either

I have a list of input values

```
List[A]
```

and a function

```
f(List[A]): Either[Failure, Success]
```

I apply the function to each element of the list, resulting in a `List[Either[Failure, Success]]`.

I would like to examine the list and if any of the values is a failure, return the first failure, otherwise return a list of the successes.

I have used the following patterns:

```scala
val allValues = list.map(f(_))
if (allValues.exists(_.isLeft)) {
  allValues.find(_.isLeft).get
} else {
  allValues.collect {
    case Right(result) => result
  }
}
```

and

```scala
val allValues = list.map(f(_))
val failures = allValues.collect { case Left(error) => error }
if (failures.nonEmpty) {
  failures(0)
} else {
  allValues.collect {
    case Right(result) => result
  }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to express this pattern?

Sometimes, I have to further process the successes through another function, again using the same pattern. For example

- Convert a JSON array into Scala models and fail if any of the JSON objects are malformed.
- Write the models to a database and fail if any of the database updates fail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds as though you'd like you transform a `List[Either[Failure, Success]]` into an `Either[Failure, List[Success]]` ? You can make this more elegant using `toLeft`.

```
result collectFirst { case Left(f) => f } toLeft {
    result collect { case Right(r) => r}
}
```

`collectFirst` accepts a `PartialFunction[A, B]` that it will apply to the first element of the `List` that has a defined output, and will return `Option[B]`. In this case, I try to extract the first `Left(f)` from the `List`, so I will get `Option[Failure]`.

Then, I call `toLeft` on the `Option[Failure]`. This will convert the single `Failure` again to `Left` if the `Option` contains a value, and the argument will produce the `Right` value if the `Option` is empty.

If the `Option` is indeed empty, then I extract the successes using `collect`, similarly to using `collectFirst`, except that it retains all elements of the `List` that the `PartialFunction` is defined for.

Comment: That's very nice! Then a pattern match to select Left or Right.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
l.collectFirst { case Left(error) => error }.getOrElse {
     l.map(_.right)
 }
```

where `l` is the list of `Either[Left, Right]`

For example:

In case there is an error

```
val l = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(3), Left(4), Right(5))
l.collectFirst { case Left(error) => error }.getOrElse {
     l.map(_.right)
 } //res0: Any = 3
```

It returns `any` as it can return `Failure` or list of  `Success`

Comment: You can use `collectFirst` to replace the combo `collect` + `headOptiion`.